# Rfc2898DeriveBytes C# not same result, equivalent Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption

When I use the method `"Rfc2898DeriveBytes"` there are different constructors.

I use these two constructors but I didn't find the same result :

C# :

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Byte[], Byte[], Int32)
```

and

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String, Byte[], Int32)
```

In the first case :

```
var pwd = Convert.FromBase64String(_pwd);
var salt = Convert.FromBase64String(_salt);
var key1 = Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd,salt,25);
byte[] resultKey1 = key1.GetBytes(16);
```

In second case :

```
var salt = Convert.FromBase64String(_salt);
var key2 = Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_pwd,salt,25);    
byte[] resultKey2 = key2.GetBytes(16);
```

---

Now in Java, the equivalence is :

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray(), byteArraySalt, 25, 128);
SecretKey temp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
```

With this Java code, the result is the same as `"resultKey2"` (in C#)

So, how can we get the same result as `"resultKey1"`(C#)  in Java ?

is this because of unsigned/signed bytes ?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Is `_pwd` actually Base64 encoded in the first case? Can you give an example of `_pwd` and `PASSWORD` that are not working?

Comment: for example _pwd (or PASSWORD in Java) : b4t7exempleLO2299rJ39bU74sJa96bBhKo94gkJOpH92qUz2110jlPmeZ9tEsT98TesTNszl713jf83ajf75dnaqlope6561782